# Used PHP then JavaScript for cookies on HTML form. Tried again with JS, I made a new JS file for the HTML. Why is my JS file not working on my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cookies

This has been driving me crazy and I've tried everything. I even tried to copy and paste the W3school tutorial into my file and that didn't work either. I am at a complete loss. I understand that this type of question has been answered in the past, and I did go through the answers and none really seemed to help. I've been working on this for days straight. I'm sure there must be some kind of error but I have no idea what it is. Please see my code below. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
    <!DOCtype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <LINK href="preferred_style.css" title="Job Listings" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <LINK href="alternate_style.css" title="Job Listings" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <LINK href="persist_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <title>Job Hunt Calc</title>

    <style>
    .topnav {
      background-color: maroon;
      overflow: hidden;
      enter code here`}

     .topnav a {
     float: left;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 30px;
     }

     .topnav a:hover {
       background-color: white;
       color: black;
     }

     .topnav a.active {
       background-color: maroon;
       color: white;
     }
     </style>

     </head>

     <body>
    <div class="header">
    <h1 id="title" onmouseover="hover()" onmouseout="normal()">Job Hunting Calculator</h1>
    </div>



   <div class="topnav">
       <a href="index.html">Home</a>
       <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
       <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
       <a href="contact1.html">Contact Us</a>
       <a href="roll.html">Time Job Hunting</a>

   </div>


     <h4>How Long Have You Been Job-Hunting?</h4>
     <form name="roll" action="https://web2.jhuep.com/~ctoren1/cgi-bin/Untitled.cgi" method=GET>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Months:</td>
    <td>
      <input name=Months size=6>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Weeks:</td>
    <td>
      <input name=Weeks size=6>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Days:</td>
    <td>
      <input name=Days size=6>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hours:</td>
    <td>
      <input name=Hours size=6>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<P>
  <input type=submit value=Calculate>
  <input type=reset value=Reset>
</P>
 </FORM>
 <script src="js/cookies.js"></script>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Here is my .JS file code:

```
    function restoreFormData()
    {
      document.forms["roll"]["Months"].value = getCookie("first name")
      document.forms["roll"]["Weeks"].value = getCookie("Weeks")
      document.forms["roll"]["Days"].value = getCookie("Days")]
      document.forms["roll"]["Hours"].value = getCookie("Hours")
    }


    setCookie("Months", Months, 90);
    setCookie("Weeks", Weeks, 90);
    setCookie("Days", Days, 90);
    setCookie("Hours", Hours, 90);

    }

    function setCookie(cName, cValue, cExpiration) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (cExpiration*24*60*60*1000));
    var expireDate = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
   document.cookie = cName + "=" + cValue + ";" + expireDate +   ";path=/";
   }

   function getCookie(cName) {
    var cookieName = cName + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
     for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while(c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
         c = c.substring(1);
     }
     if (c.indexOf(cookieName) == 0) {
          return c.substring(cookieName.length, c.length);
     }
   }
   return "";
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? What are the errors you're running into? What do you mean "not working", can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I've tried putting my JS into a JS validator and it came out fine. I tried to validate my HTML on Validator.nu and it came out fine too. What I mean by not working is that the JavaScript I wrote does not run and does not create the cookies for the HTML file. No errors are coming up so that's why I don't know what to do.

Comment: You have a trailing `]` on the first "Days" line: `document.forms["roll"]["Days"].value = getCookie("Days")]`. Where are you getting the `Months`, `Weeks`, `Days` and `Hours` variables from? You have a lonely `}` after you set the four cookies. Is this all of your code or is there more? And you are getting the "first name" cookie for the "Months" field.

Comment: Thanks! the first name thing was just a typo. problem was happening before that. The Months, days weeks, etc. are from my CGI code. I guess I should add that?